# CentOS 7 Application auto close when added to Show Applications

Tags: centos

I installed MATLAB on CentOS 7 whose installer did not add an icon to Show Applications. I have created a desktop file `matlab.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications` as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=9.2.0
Name=Matlab
Path=/opt/matlab/R2017a/bin
Exec=/opt/matlab/R2017a/bin/matlab
Comment=Matlab
Icon=/opt/matlab/R2017a/usr/share/icon/matlabicon_128.png
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.15
```

The issue is MATLAB runs, showing the welcome window, and I can see the process starts when I run `ps -e | grep MATLAB`. But then the process is closed! When I run MATLAB using terminal and command `matlab`, it opens and works without any problems.

What is the problem here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have got answer answer on CentOS Forum. I decided to answer this question as nobody has done it so far.

MATLAB command accepts additional options. One of them is:

> `matlab -desktop`
>   Start MATLAB without a controlling terminal. Use this option when you start MATLAB from a window manager menu or desktop icon

So essentially adding -desktop to property `Exec` solved the problem:

```
Exec=/opt/matlab/R2017a/bin/matlab -desktop
```